# Running SBT behind proxy

Tags: bash, scala, proxy, sbt

I am trying to run SBT example behind corporate proxy.

```
sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

I set proxy as per instructions:

```
export   SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS    -Dhttp.proxyHost=myusername:mypassword@correcthost  -Dhttp.proxyPort=correctport   -Dhttps.proxyHost=myusername:mypassword@correcthost -Dhttps.proxyPort=correctport"
```

Error that is showing:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt.sbt-giter8-resolver#sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12;0.1.3: public: unable to get resource for org/scala-sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver#sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12;0.1.3: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12/0.1.3/sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12-0.1.3.pom: java.net.UnknownHostException: myusername:mypassword@correcthost: invalid IPv6 address
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Retrieval of org.scala-sbt.sbt-giter8-resolver:sbt-giter8-resolver:0.1.3 failed.
```

Why is it throwing `invalid IPv6 address` error?
How to properly set proxy for SBT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Proxy which requires authentication, I have a solution for you :)

SBT has a very hard time handling proxy requiring authentication. The solution is to bypass this authentication, if you cannot turn off your proxy on demand (corporate proxy for example). To do so, I suggest you use a squid proxy, and configure it with your username and password to access your corporate proxy. See : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/squid Then, you can set JAVA_OPTS or SBT_OPTS environment variables so that SBT connects to your own local squid proxy instead of your corporate proxy :

```
export JAVA_OPTS = "-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"
```

(just c/c this in your bashrc without modifying anything and it should work fine).

The trick is that Squid Proxy does not require any authentication, and acts as an intermediate between SBT and your other proxy.

If you have troubles in applying this advise, please let me know.

Regards,

Edgar

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `-Dhttps.proxyHost=myusername:mypassword@correcthost` shouldn't be formatted like that. Instead you provide the following setup in your `~/.profile` and you'll have to set the variables of course:

`export SBT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST} -Dhttp.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT} -Dhttps.proxyHost=${PROXY_HOST} -Dhttps.proxyPort=${PROXY_PORT} -Dhttp.proxyUser=$USER -Dhttp.proxyPassword=$PASS -Dhttps.proxyUser=$USER -Dhttps.proxyPassword=$PASS"`

So the user and password are provided in their own settings override (`-Dhttps.proxyUser/Password`).